# Examples of Dynamics AX 2009 programming?

Tags: sample, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm just learning to program Dynamics AX 2009. So far I got the dev system running, I got some background about the architecture.

Now I'm looking for some walkthrough-samples to learn more about programming in this system.

Are there some samples available online? Can someone point me to some learning help? Maybe to some good AX-programming related blogs?

How did you learn to program DAX9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some other links you may find helpful.

[Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 SDK on the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/)

[mfp's two cents blog](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/mfp/archive)

[Dynamics Ax Performance team blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20100323003015/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/axperf/default.aspx)

[Issues concerning X++ blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/x/)

Answer (score 5):

Great start: http://www.axaptapedia.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

This is the list of AX blogs I follow: http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user/02229624826229113183/label/ax

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft AX Customer Source](http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/customer/en-us/access-customersource/default.aspx) has a lot of technical references and training available as does
[AX User Group](http://www.axug.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There also 4 books you can use to get started;

Use these 3 for basic code and developments;

MorphX IT
Dynamics AX Getting Started
Inside Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 2nd Edition

This one is more advanced and is based on most common requested developments that the author came accross;

Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2009 Development Cookbook

Answer (score 0):

You can find an English e-book with helpful samples in a zip-file [here](http://sirprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/03/e-book-introduction-to-axapta-x-and.html)

In case if you to learn developing in AX 2012 [click here, for useful links.](http://axwonders.blogspot.com/2012/01/helpful-ax-2012-links.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are few samples available here:

Fleet Management 
The Fleet Management sample application for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 provides an example of how to implement common functionality in Microsoft Dynamics AX. Use it to learn about how to implement your own module or integrating application. 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DynamicsAX2009FM/

Facility Management:
The Facility Management sample application for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 provides an example of how to implement common functionality in Microsoft Dynamics AX. Use it to learn about how to implement your own module or integrating application. 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FCMDynamicsAX2009

Thanks